# Python estimate running time and graph it

Tags: linux, python

I'm on manjaro, I once asked a friend to calculate how much time it would take for my python algorithm to finish running. He told me the time and graph it. I never asked him how he did it.

Is there a Linux software or module or whatever, where you can write your script and then use the software to estimate the running time and graph, graphing is optional.

Notes:

- I don't want to know the complexity of my algorithm, I already know
  it.
- I don't want to know the execution time after the script has been executed, for that I could use `time python script.py` but some of my programs take days to run since I'm analyzing big CSVs so I want to estimate the time before running the program.